# Unable to read .cdb file using Python

Tags: python, database, binary, cdb

I have a .cdb file generated by a 3d-printing software that I assume saves all the printing parameters, and on my machine the size of the file is 25.7 MB. I tried reading the file using Python [pure-cdb](https://python-pure-cdb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) library. However, after running this code:

```
import cdblib
with open('First.cdb', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
reader = cdblib.Reader64(data)
for key, value in reader.iteritems():
print('+{},{}:{}->{}'.format(len(key), len(value), key, value))
```

I do not get any output.
In contrast, when I run

```
len(reader)
```

I get 5815070385157957162 as the output.

What may be causing it and how can I read the file in the human-readable format?

Comment: You are missing an indent on your print statement

Comment: Oh, yeah. I just pasted it wrong. I do have the indent in the actual code.